# Downgrade "Windows 10" 1511 to build 10240 without: update & security -> recovery

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to downgrade an already updated "Windows 10" back to an earlier "Windows 10" build without the recovery option, which is removed in 1511?

We have problems with the 1511 update and need to roll back some computers to build 10240. Our Antivirus Software seems to work correctly only on this previous build.

Any help is very appreciated.

fyi:

[image: Windows 10 1511 has no recovery option to roll back to earlier build!]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't run a disk cleanup to remove the old installation, you should be able to do the following:

1. Click on Start Menu
2. `Settings` -> `Update & Security` -> `Recovery`
3. Look for '`Go back to an earlier build`'
4. Click '`Get started`'

[image: Go back to an earlier build]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in Windows 10 1511 this option seems to be removed. See my screenshot above.

Comment: Do you have a C:\Windows.old folder?

Comment: No. This Windows 10 was freshly installed weeks ago. The 1511 update was a normal update.

Comment: November update 1511 was considered a major update and as such should have created a C:\Windows.old folder to restore back to the previous build. Unless you mean you fresh installed an image already at 1511, it sounds like it got deleted, either by disk cleanup/CCleaner or manually. Without this folder I don't believe there is any way to roll back.

Comment: I apologize, you are right, there is a C:\Windows.old folder. How do I use this?

Comment: My knowledge only goes this far now I'm afraid, I understood that with the Windows.old folder you would have the option to roll back under Recovery. The only place I can think left to check is under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features, there is a button 'View installed updates'. I don't think this update should feature here as this is only usually minor updates, but it might be worth checking. Sorry.

Comment: Then, isn't there any other method (such as modifying the build number) to allow the installation of a new version keeping the applications and settings?